# Display nodes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, nodes

I have a requirement to traverse through an XML document and display the nodes that satisfy a specific criteria.  I was able to get the file over http and get the nodes that satisfy the criteria from that. But I couldn't present those on the screen nor can I see them.

I tried all different ways but in vain,

XML Structure :

```
<routeElement>
 <Service>
  <name>RetrieveEmployeeDetailV001</name>
 </Service>
 <Service>
  <name>RetrieveEmployeeAccountDetailV001</name>
 </Service>
</routeElement>
```

This is the piece of code I am stuck at...

```
xmlDocument.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");
finalData=xmlDocument.selectNodes("//service");
```

I used different ways to access the child nodes of finalData.

```
finalData[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
finalData.childNodes[0].nodeValue; 
finalData[0].getElementByTagName("service");
finalData[0].firstChild
```

etc etc. But nothing has worked out.Can you please suggest a solution to the problem ?

Comment: Are you using any javascript frameworks? The link provided in the answer below is for a .NET4.0 component, which is NOT javascript. I wonder if you're trying to do too much of the underlying work yourself, when you could be using something to abstract a lot of the browser inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select nodes with javascript/xpath, you can use `document.evaluate`. Something like:

```
var xresult = document.evaluate('//service',xmlDocument, null, 
                          XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null),
              result,
              ret = [];
while (result = xresult.iterateNext()) {
   ret.push(result);
};
//=> the `ret`-array should contain the nodes you searched
```

This will work in most browsers, except IE. For IE use [SelectNodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes.aspx)

Alternatively I think regular DOM-methods should work, in this case `xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName('service')` would return a [`NodeList`](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/xmldom/quickref/obj_nodelist.html)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. I am using IE so I have gone with selectNodes.